# Showing space of functions with lipschitz norm is complete

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I have a Banach space, $X$, given by all the complex valued functions $x: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ where $x(0) = 0$. And I've shown that the following defines a norm on $X$:

$$\|x\| = inf \{ \beta : |x(s)-x(t)| \le \beta |s-t| \}$$

I'm now struggling to show that this space is complete. So far I'm considering a cauchy sequence $x_n(t)$ and then I can use the norm to say that for all $s,t$,  $|x_n(s) + x_n(t) - x_m(s) + x_m(t)| \to 0$ but I'm not really sure that use that is,

Thanks

Comment: First show that $(x_n(t))$ is a Cauchy sequence for every $t$. Then show that the pointwise limit $x$ is Lipschitz continuous with $\lVert x\rVert \leqslant \sup \lVert x_n\rVert$. Then show that $\lVert x_n - x\rVert \to 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm having a bit of trouble with the first step, do you think you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: You have $\lvert x(t) - x(s)\rvert \leqslant \lVert x\rVert\cdot \lvert t-s\rvert$ for all $s,t$. Pick a convenient fixed $s$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've done the middle step fine. For the last step I have that $|x_n(t) - x(t) - x_n(s) + x(s)| \le |x_n(t) - x_n(s)| + |x(t) - x(s)| \le (\beta_n + \beta)|s-t|$. I'm struggling to make any inferences from this that the inf must then be 0?

Comment: $x_n(t) - x(t) - x_n(s) + x(s) = \lim\limits_{m\to\infty} x_n(t) - x_m(t) - x_n(s) + x_m(s)$

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm just coming back to this question again, I'm still not sure I entirely have this. In your first comment when you say $||x|| \le \sup ||x_n||$ how do we know that $\sup||x_n||$ is in fact finite? Thanks

Comment: $(x_n)$ is by assumption a Cauchy sequence, and every Cauchy sequence [in any normed space] is bounded (pick $k$ such that $\lVert x_n - x_m\rVert \leqslant 1$ for $n,m \geqslant k$, then the triangle inequality shows $\lVert x_n\rVert \leqslant \lVert x_k\rVert + 1$ for $n\geqslant k$).

Answer (score 1):

The sketch of proof is always the same for these questions:

- if $(x_n)$ is Cauchy sequence, then for each $u$, $(x_n(u))$ is Cauchy sequence.
- define $x(u) = \lim x_n(u)$. Then show that $x$ is Lipschitz continuous (pass to the limit in the definition of the sequence).
- finally, prove that $x_n \to x$ (pass to the limit is the definition of: $(x_n(u))$ is a Cauchy sequence).

Comment: This is the method I'm trying to follow however I'm struggling at the first bullet point unfortunately so any tips would be very much appreciated!

Comment: this is just $|x_{n}(u) - x_{n+p}(u)| \le \|x_n - x_{n+p}\| $, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It also follows quite nicely from showing $x_n \rightarrow x$ first.

---

**1.** As $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, exists $N$ such that for all $n,m \ge N$,

$$ |(x_n - x_m)(u) - (x_n- x_m)(t) | \le \epsilon |u-t| $$ 
for al $u,t \in [-1,1]$. Letting $t = 0$ we obtain a Cauchy sequence $(x_n(u))$ allowing us to define $x(u) := \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n(u)$. By limiting $m \rightarrow \infty$, we obtain that $x_n \rightarrow x$ uniformly.

---

**2.** Thus, 
$$| (x_n - x) |_u^t |  \le | (x_n - x_m)|_u^t | + |(x_m - x ) |_u^t | \\
 \le \epsilon |u-t| + |(x_m - x ) (u)| + |(x_m -x) (t) |   $$
By limiting $m \rightarrow \infty$ and uniform convergence derived previously, we obtain
$$ |(x_n- x)|_u^t| \le \epsilon |x-t| \Rightarrow || x_n - x ||_{lip} \le \epsilon$$ 
So by limiting $n$ to infinity, we have $|| x_n -x ||_{lip} \rightarrow 0 $.

---

**3.** From above, we know that $x_n - x \in X$ for all $n$, and as the space is a vector space, $x = x_n + (x- x_n) \in X$.